# Are caption(table) and legend(fieldset) the only html first descendant restrictions?

Tags: html

```
<legend>, if used, must immediately follow <fieldset>
<caption>, if used, must immediately follow <table>
```

Are there other such "must be the first descendant" restrictions in HTML?
*(and is there a place you would you find such info, short of reading every single tag's complete rules?)* [mostly care about html5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through the [MDN Tag Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) I was able to find only one other such restriction: `<figcaption>` must be either the first or last element in a `<figure>` block

Answer (score 1):

You can use them at other places, but for ex. legend gives a unique styling for heading on Fieldset, it won't work, if you miss it similarly caption has some specific meaning for tables.

These are just pre-defined standards.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
legend {
  padding: 2px;
  color: purple
}
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Heading inside Legend</legend>
    <input type="text">
  </fieldset>

  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
    <caption>Caption inside Table</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: MDN (example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption ) seems to indicate the positioning is a requirement, so I am assuming using it elsewhere is undefined behavior, and thus the browser (or whatever) is free to do with it as it pleases if it is found elsewhere